# Regex conditional if-then in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

How can I create a JavaScript-based regex for the URL below that looks for the exact word `stuff`? If the word exists then it looks for a numeric value, `(\d+)`.

```
http://myurl.com/app/stuff/detail/file/1234
```

I tried, almost everything here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: There are no conditionals in javascript regexes.

Comment: Why is `/\/stuff\/.*?\/(\d+)/` not enough?

Comment: As a matter of fact it was enough; thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through positive lookahead. Javascript supports positive lookahead. Positive lookahead is used to check a line which contains a specific string.

```
(?:.*?\/(\d+)\/.*?)?(?=\bstuff\b)(?:.*?\/(\d+).*)?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dU0tL1)

Comment: I don't get why you have used lookahead here, it seems to work without as well. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Javascript's implementation of Regex does not include conditionals.

You can read about the available features at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Comment: it could, see my solution.

Comment: Yes, but this uses regex lookaheads, and not conditionals. Also, if using lookaheads, I believe `(?=stuff).*?\/(\d+)\/` is more concise.